# writing soft objects in a powershell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

In my c# cmdlet I want to write out objects that are essentially dictionary. Ie the cmdlet doesn't know a concrete type for object at compile time.

Suppose I have

```
myobj1["Size"] = 10
myobj1["color"] = "Red"
myobj2["Size"] = 20
myobj2["color"] = "Blue"
```

I want to inject into the pipeline objects that will look like

```
Size              Color
----              -----
10                Red
20                Blue
```

I have tried

```
var dict = myObj as IDictioanry<string,object> // it does implement IDictionary
WriteObject(dict);
```

this just produces 2 fields on output Key and Value. Not what I want

I also tried loading into an expandoobject - this does the same thing as a dictionary.

Resolved:

```
        var pso = new PSObject();
        foreach (var k in myobj.PropertyNames)
        {
            pso.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty(k, de.Properties[k]));
        }
        WriteObject(pso);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$myobj = @()

$myobj += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Size = 10
        Color= "Red"
        }

$myobj += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Size = 20
        Color= "Blue"
        }

$myobj | Where-Object Size -eq 10
```

or on single lines:

```
$myobj = @()
$myobj += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Size = 10;Color= "Red"}
$myobj += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Size = 20;Color= "Blue"}            
$myobj | Where-Object Size -eq 20
```

or move the new object part into a function:

```
function New-MyObject([int]$size,[string]$color)
{
    return New-Object PSObject -Property @{Size = $size;Color= "$color"}
}

$myobj = @()  
$myobj += New-MyObject 10 Red   
$myobj += New-MyObject -size 20 -color Blue        
$myobj | Where-Object Size -eq 20
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea here, the poster should be creating PSObjects, but your code is PowerShell and he/she is writing a cmdlet in c#. Might be better to show how to do it in c#.

Comment: @briantist - ooops, I totally missed the C# part. I haven't written cmdlets in C# in years. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: he is indeed writing a cmdlet in c#

Comment: however that was enough of a hint to get me working - edited q to include answer